# Display rows even if the column returns an empty result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Following is my query:-

```
SELECT u.name as title, 
COALESCE(f.field_full_name_value,'None Provided') as f.field_full_name_value,
u.mail, u.created, u.access, u.uid, COUNT(a.uid) AS times
FROM site_users u, site_node_view_count a, site_field_data_field_full_name f 
where a.uid = u.uid and f.entity_id = u.uid 
GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY times desc
```

What this does is to show user's site access details. The problem arises when I try to show Full name (f.field_full_name_value) as the column. What happens is that if some user has no Full name (f.field_full_name_value) entered, the whole row doesn't show. I was hoping that wherever the f.field_full_name_value is not entered, the field can show empty field but still show values of other fields.

I tried using `COALESCE` as shown in the query but it gives me error.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this query instead of above.

```
SELECT 
    u.name as title,
    u.mail,
    u.created,
    u.access,
    u.uid,
    COALESCE(f.field_full_name_value,'None Provided') AS field_full_name_value,
    COUNT(a.uid) AS times
FROM
    site_users u,
    site_node_view_count a,
    site_field_data_field_full_name f
WHERE
    a.uid = u.uid AND f.entity_id = u.uid
GROUP BY u.uid
ORDER BY times DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query will return the result you need

```
 SELECT u.name as title ,
    CASE
    WHEN f.field_full_name_value IS NULL
    THEN 'None Provided'
    ELSE  f.field_full_name_value
    END  as full_name_value, u.mail, u.created, u.access, u.uid, COUNT(a.uid) AS times
    FROM site_users u
    LEFT JOIN site_field_data_field_full_name f on u.uid =f.entity_id 
    INNER JOIN site_node_view_count a on a.uid = u.uid
    GROUP BY u.name
    ORDER BY times DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OUTER JOIN , hope this helps . . .

```
SELECT u.name as title, 
COALESCE(f.field_full_name_value,'None Provided') as field_full_name_value,
u.mail, 
u.created, 
u.access, 
u.uid, 
COUNT(a.uid) AS times

FROM site_users u 

LEFT JOIN site_node_view_count a
ON a.uid = u.uid

LEFT OUTER JOIN site_field_data_field_full_name f 
ON f.entity_id = u.uid 

GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY times desc
```